# ReactJS:cannot display html text on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot seem to figure out what I shall do to correct the issue:

I always got no display on the browser, where I expect to see "Hello React".

Here is the HelloWorld code:

ReactDOM.render(

## Hello, React!

,document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Does React automatically transform JSX? I think you should use `babel`, `typescript`.... for it.

Comment: I think you have missed a starting `<body>` tag in your HTML.
And the script tags should be placed before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Yep, the code was messed up when formatting on SO. It got worse when I tried to edit it later when I see your comment. Now it is even printing out THe  result in SO, and missing out the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code base to understand basic of React JS **(have been used latest version react-15.0.0)** -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
   <!-- use this as script file "fb.me/react-15.0.0.js"
    "fb.me/react-dom-15.0.0.js"
    cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js" -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="greeting-div"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var Greeting = React.createClass({ 
            
    render: function() { 
        return ( <div>{this.props.children} </div>) 
    } 
        }); 
        
ReactDOM.render(
 <div>
        <Greeting>hello Aby</Greeting>
         <h1>HELLO</h1>
        </div>,
    document.getElementById('greeting-div') );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your example here, https://codesandbox.io/s/ElRmqWK5Y
what I will suggest download the react package and run your code there in the beginning, and what I think about your code is you should add react library first than react-dom.

Comment: +Abhishek, can I ask why I'd download the react package first?

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing < body > in your code , try to add it and tell us if it works

Answer (score 0):

So basically the problem is that you don't transpile your jsx. For your simple example what you can do if you don't want to configure transpiling 'explicitly' with some bundler you can add Babel library and change

```
<script type="text/jsx">
```

to

```
<script type="text/babel">
```

Let's have a look here, but please remember that jsfiddle uses babel behind (quite sure):

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83023/

Also let me paste example from babel docs. Especially take a look for added babel lib + script type.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Your custom script here -->
<script type="text/babel">
  const getMessage = () => "Hello World";
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getMessage();
</script>
```